# crystalline structure of single crystal wafers used for MEMS fabrication

Tags: etching

When they say that we have a {1 0 0} single crystal wafer, I know that the surface normal to the wafer is oriented in the <1 0 0> family direction, but if I draw a line on the wafer, parallel to my primary flat, does it indicate a crystallographic direction family too? Like <1 0 0> or <1 0 1>. I mean it's obvious that it cannot be <1 1 1> due to the FCC lattice of Si(I am making the assumption that the thin plane of the primary flat is at exact right angles to the wafer surface, if that angle is allowed to be 54 degrees, it can also be a <1 1 1> ), but it can surely be directed at none of the crystallographic directions at all, so the question is, if I draw a line on the wafer surface parallel to the primary flat, will it be directed towards the <1 0 0> or the <1 0 1> family, or does the manufacturing process just slice an arbitrary flat out of the Si ingot before slicing it into wafers?

Comment: Specify what size of wafer your are using.  The flats/Notches changes in the different family sizes.  But in general, the flat locations (or Notches) mean something wrt to the Crystal directions.

Comment: I am NOT using any wafer family as of yet, fabrication lab does not start until the next semester. Now, we are just studying the theory behind MEMS and was learning about etching processes, so the question just popped into my head. BTW I thank you for at least taking taking an interest in my question, no one else seems to care :) Could you elaborate a bit more about it, if it's not too complicated?